# AngularJS Typeahead open dropdownlist on down arrow key and also on a button clicked

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-typeahead

I am using AngularJS Typeahead directive and it works fine but i have two issues
1- I want to open the drop down list when the down arrow key(key code 40) is pressed
2- I have a button and i want this button to open also the drop down list; the same as above
[image]

Comment: any feedback as soon as possible

Comment: Please setup a plunkr or jsfiddle

Comment: I provided an answer [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31564461/angularjs-show-typeahead-on-button-click/31568886#31568886) which you may find accommodating.